# Пропадает перевод строки при вставке в VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, форматирование

Пример моей проблемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее копирую выделенную область (тег с переводом строки перед ним):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее вставляю скопированный текст в положение курсора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, форматирование vs code убрало перевод строки перед тегом.
Все расширения для xml и html у меня отключены - включена только дефолтная поддержка html от vs code.
Как мне изменить форматирование, чтобы перевод строки перед тегом сохранялся?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему установкой нового форматировщика: [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemname=hookyqr.beautify).

После установки расширения необходимо установить его в качестве форматировщика для `HTML`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]